# $A$ is an $n\times n$ matrix where $n$ is an even number. If $A^2 = 0$ what must also be true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The answer choices are:

1. $\operatorname{rank}(A) = 0$
2. $\operatorname{rank}(A) \leq \frac{n}{2}$ (and possibly $>0$)
3. $\operatorname{rank}(A) \leq n-1$ (and possibly $> \frac{n}{2}$)

I know that 1. is false, but I don't know about 2 and 3.

Comment: the second one must be true.

Comment: Hint: there are two inequalities that relate the rank of two matrices $B$ and $C$, and the rank of $BC$.

Comment: @yanko even with the "(and possibly)"?

Comment: @ Arthur, consider the matrix with (1,0) and (0,0) this is of rank $1$ and it's squared is zero.

Comment: @yanko I missed $\geq$, thought it was $>$. In fact, checking it, it _was_ $>$ before amWhy changed it.

Answer (score 0):

a counter example for $3$ is the 4*4 identity matrix with one of the 1's replaced by zero.

lets prove that $2$ must be true, you know that $$n=dim (Im A) +dim (ker A)$$
let $v\in ImA$ then by assumpation, $v\in Ker(A)$ it follows that $Im A \subseteq Ker (A)$ and therefore $Rank A =dim Im(A) \leq \frac{n}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

A proof for the second statement. We have $A^2 = A[a_1 \ldots a_n] = O$. Take any $x \in \text{coll}(A)$. Then $x = c_1a_1 + \ldots +c_na_n$. But then
$$Ax = A(c_1a_1 + \ldots c_na_n) = c_1Aa_1 + \ldots c_nAa_n = 0,$$ 
hence $x \in \text{null}(A)$ and $\text{nullity}(A) \geqslant \text{rank}(A)$. But then,
$$\text{rank}(A) + \text{rank}(A) \leqslant \text{rank}(A) + \text{nullity}(A) = n \Rightarrow rank (A) \leqslant n/2 $$

Comment: yes this is exactly the same proof as mine with Ker replaced by nullity...